# How to display PDO rows results vertically?

Tags: php, html

CODE!

```
<?php

    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT userID, FullName, BirthDate, DeathDate FROM name');
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            extract($row);      

echo "<td align='center'><div class='listxtNB' style='width:30px;'>" .$row['userID']. "</div></td>";
echo "<td align='center'><div class='listxtNB' style='width:135px;'>" .$row['FullName']. "</div></td>";
echo "<td align='center'><div class='listxtNB' style='width:95px;'>" .$row['BirthDate']. "</div></td>";
echo "<td align='center'><div class='listxtNB' style='width:95px;'>" .$row['DeathDate']. "</div></td>";
echo "<td align='center'><div class='listxtNB' style='width:45px;'><a href='editform.php?edit_id=".$row['userID']."'>EDIT</a></div></td>";
echo "<td align='center'><div class='listxtNB' style='width:45px;'><a href='?delete_id=".$row['userID']."' onclick='return confirm('sure to delete ?')>DELETE</a></div></td>";
echo "</tr></table>";
?>
```

[looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvilH.png)

[Needs to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWtL0.png)

Comment: Where is the beginning of the <tr> html row?

Comment: You need to start a new row and not end the table

Comment: See my answer, you are building the table wrong during the while loop when looping through your rows

Comment: Don't use `extract()`.

Comment: Why are you using `extract($row)` **Dont** Specially as you are then using the $row occurances by name anyway

Comment: Well Formed HTML is the answer you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

You have to slightly adjust your code to the following:

```
<?php
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT userID, FullName, BirthDate, DeathDate FROM name');
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)  {
    echo "<table>";
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        extract($row);  
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td align='center'><div class='listxtNB' style='width:30px;'>" .$row['userID']. "</div></td>";
        echo "<td align='center'><div class='listxtNB' style='width:135px;'>" .$row['FullName']. "</div></td>";
        echo "<td align='center'><div class='listxtNB' style='width:95px;'>" .$row['BirthDate']. "</div></td>";
        echo "<td align='center'><div class='listxtNB' style='width:95px;'>" .$row['DeathDate']. "</div></td>";
        echo "<td align='center'><div class='listxtNB' style='width:45px;'><a href='editform.php?edit_id=".$row['userID']."'>EDIT</a></div></td>";
        echo "<td align='center'><div class='listxtNB' style='width:45px;'><a href='?delete_id=".$row['userID']."' onclick='return confirm('sure to delete ?')>DELETE</a></div></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        }
    echo "</table>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: And remove the unnecessary and very nasty `extract($row)`

Comment: @RiggsFolly, well that's not related to the question. No Idea where he might need it for in further code?

Answer (score 0):

This should work I guess:

```
 <?php

        $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT userID, FullName, BirthDate, DeathDate FROM name');
        $stmt->execute();

        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
        {
            while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                extract($row); 

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td align='center'><div class='listxtNB' style='width:30px;'>" .$row['userID']. "</div></td>";
                echo "<td align='center'><div class='listxtNB' style='width:135px;'>" .$row['FullName']. "</div></td>";
                echo "<td align='center'><div class='listxtNB' style='width:95px;'>" .$row['BirthDate']. "</div></td>";
                echo "<td align='center'><div class='listxtNB' style='width:95px;'>" .$row['DeathDate']. "</div></td>";
                echo "<td align='center'><div class='listxtNB' style='width:45px;'><a href='editform.php?edit_id=".$row['userID']."'>EDIT</a></div></td>";
                echo "<td align='center'><div class='listxtNB' style='width:45px;'><a href='?delete_id=".$row['userID']."' onclick='return confirm('sure to delete ?')>DELETE</a></div></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
    ?>
```

Comment: Don't forget to do a table start and end tag within the rowCount > 0 if-statement for valid html, see my answer (browser parsers will correct this I guess, but still...)

Comment: thanks all got all 3 worked , didn't forget the table start tag had it just forgot to post here ... but thanks again..

Comment: Again, it is not a necessity to declare the table tags right here. You can do that where it is appropriate. If it is appropriate then sure, append and prepend the while loop with the necessary <table> and </table> tags.

Answer (score 0):

The table tag it's closed in the LOOP, and you don't need a lot of echos

```
<?php

$stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT userID, FullName, BirthDate, DeathDate FROM name');
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
{
    echo "<table>";
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        extract($row);      
    echo "<tr><td align='center'><div class='listxtNB' style='width:30px;'>" .$row['userID']. "</div></td>
    <td align='center'><div class='listxtNB' style='width:135px;'>" .$row['FullName']. "</div></td>
    <td align='center'><div class='listxtNB' style='width:95px;'>" .$row['BirthDate']. "</div></td>
    <td align='center'><div class='listxtNB' style='width:95px;'>" .$row['DeathDate']. "</div></td>
    <td align='center'><div class='listxtNB' style='width:45px;'><a href='editform.php?edit_id=".$row['userID']."'>EDIT</a></div></td>
    <td align='center'><div class='listxtNB' style='width:45px;'><a href='?delete_id=".$row['userID']."' onclick='return confirm('sure to delete ?')>DELETE</a></div></td>
     </tr>";
   }
   echo "</table>";
   }
 ?>
```

Comment: This will result in invalid html. See my tag. You forgot to both open the table tag and tr tag (browser parsers will correct this I guess, but still...)

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren Yes, Thanks for your reply (y)

Comment: Not necessarily. There is a chance that the <table> gets created elsewhere.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.